# YAML/JSON required attribute is not working for object properties

Tags: python, yaml, jsonschema

I have a yml file that looks like:

```
mysql:
  db_pswd: "abcd"
  db_name: "pqrs"
```

I am trying to validate this config using jsonschema library from python for below schema:

```
mysql:
  type: object
  properties:
    db_pswd:
      type: string
    db_name:
      type: string
  required: ["db_pswd", "db_name"]
```

required: ["db_pswd"]*

And for testing purpose, when I remove the required property from config file, validation is not showing error.

Comment: Could you please correctly format your YAML in code blocks? I can't tell what they look like unless they are in code blocks.

Comment: Please check it now. @Relequestual

Comment: OK, thanks for updating. What JSON Schema do you have so far? `mysql` at the root level is not a valid schema keyword.

Comment: I think I see your problem. For your json instance, the root level is an object, which has a property `mysql`, which has a value of an object... does this help you understand what you've missed here?

Comment: Well, actually no. It would be really helpful if you could be more descriptive. Thanks already. @Relequestual

Comment: OK. Your "YAML instance" is that in the YAML file. It contains an object at the root level which has one key:value, where the key is mysql and the value is an object. If the value was an empty object, can you create a schema to validate that YAML instance? Try using https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net to test your schema. You can use https://www.json2yaml.com to convert between YAML and JSON if that's helpful.

Comment: Hi @Relequestual. Found the solution. Declared "mysql" as property of another "object" above it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. I'll now post my full JSON Schema solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON Schema you have defined (in YAML) has a key of `mysql` at the root level.

You need to define that an object is required, with a property of `mysql`. You have two layers of properties in your "JSON instance" (or yaml instance / file).

To achieve this, you want a schema like the following...

```js
type: object
properties:
    mysql:
    type: object
    properties:
      db_pswd:
        type: string
      db_name:
        type: string
    required: 
      - "db_pswd"
      - "db_name"
required: 
  - "mysql"
```